# How can I use debian_chroot in bashrc to identify the chroot env?

Tags: bash, debian, chroot, bashrc

I see the following in `~/.bashrc` :

```
 if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
     debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
 fi
```

which means if the variable is not set, and the file exists and is readable, then set the file's content to the variable.

Am I supposed to write something to that file while preparing to chroot?
If yes, then I'll have to remove that file at the end of chroot job!

*any explanation or suggestions will be appreciated.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This variable is just for building the default PS1 shell prompt down below:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

So it is not essential to create the file, although it can be nice having the prompt identifying where you are.

As you can see -r tests for a file and if the user can read it, and if it exists, debian_chroot gets the content of it, so create `/etc/debian_chroot` *inside* the chroot with the wording you want. (inside, do not do it at the true root, as won't be inside the chroot )

So if your chroot is at `/mnt`, the file you would need to modify is `/mnt/etc/debian_chroot` (and not `/etc/debian_chroot`).

Comment: By the way, I also edited you post to reference the correct path of /etc/bash.bashrc

Comment: yes i want to see in my prompt that i'm in chroot like `(chroot_env)user@hostname:~$`  , and as i see the "debian_chroot" is always null , i want it to have a value when i'm in chroot :)

Comment: I completed the answer.

Comment: (your post implies you are trying to do it at the true root, and that is why it is not behaving as you expect)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I corrected your edit since the OP was probably referring to `~/.bashrc`. The default `.bashrc` files on Debian-based distributions contain the lines quoted in the question, there's no reason to assume the OP meant `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: Could be. My .bashrc does not have it, and my /etc... has the PS1 he mentions.

Comment: thanks bro for your explaination i accepted your answer , but i just found another solution(away of creating/removing a file) , i'm testing it right now , i'm not sure if i can post it as answer or add it to the question ....

Comment: You can always modify the PS1 too. It is more appropriate to post it as an answer to yourself.